# How can I convert a base 10 (decimal) string to an array of bytes _directly_ in C#?

Tags: c#, string, arrays, radix

I'm looking to take a variable length string input, interpret it numerically, and parse it into a byte array, while imposing **no limitations** on its length.

I have binary and hex done:

```
public static byte[] GetHexBytes(this string hex, bool preTrimmed = false)
{
    if (!preTrimmed)
    {
        hex = hex.Trim();
        if (hex.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            hex = hex.Substring(2);
        else if (hex.StartsWith("16#"))
            hex = hex.Substring(3);
    }

    if (hex.Length % 2 != 0) hex = hex.PadLeft(hex.Length + 1, '0');

    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
         .ToArray();
}

public static byte[] GetBinaryBytes(this string binary, bool preTrimmed = false)
{
    if (!preTrimmed)
    {
        binary = binary.Trim();
        if (binary.StartsWith("0b", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) || binary.StartsWith("2#"))
            binary = binary.Substring(2);
    }

    if (binary.Length % 8 != 0) binary = binary.PadLeft(binary.Length + 8 - binary.Length % 8, '0');

    return Enumerable.Range(0, binary.Length)
         .Where(x => x % 8 == 0)
         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(binary.Substring(x, 8), 2))
         .ToArray();
}

public static byte[] GetDecimalBytes(this string dec, bool preTrimmed = false)
{
    if (!preTrimmed)
    {
        dec = dec.Trim();
        if (dec.StartsWith("10#"))
            dec = dec.Substring(3);
    }

    //???
}
```

Is it possible to do this conversion in a forward manner, similar to the hex and binary versions (start at the beginning of the string, working forward)?

If not, can it be done working in reverse in such a way that doesn't impose any limitations on the length of the string, without using something like System.Numerics or BigInteger (doing it manually, from the string)?

I'd like it to handle any string length, up to the maximum string length of C# (1,073,741,823).

### Examples

```
"FF".GetHexBytes() => [ 0xFF ]
"11111111".GetBinaryBytes() => [ 0xFF ]
"255".GetDecimalBytes() => [ 0xFF ]

"FFFF".GetHexBytes() => [ 0xFF, 0xFF ]
"1111111111111111".GetBinaryBytes() => [ 0xFF, 0xFF ]
"65535".GetDecimalBytes() => [ 0xFF, 0xFF ]
```

Comment: If i understood you, you can convert a string to a byte array by `byte[] byteKey = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("yourString")`

Comment: Give an example of input and output?

Comment: I get the impression that you want the result such that e.g. `"0xFFFFFFFF".GetHexBytes() == "4294967295".GetDecimalBytes()`, since `0xFFFFFFFF == 4294967295`. Which naturally extends to other values. Is that impression correct?

Comment: @Zippy: no, I want the input interpreted as a number. GetDecimalBytes("255") == GetBinaryBytes("11111111") == GetHexBytes("FF")

Comment: @Ehryk: You really should clarify the post, ideally giving multiple input and output examples. It's pretty unclear at the moment.

Comment: Why would you not want to use BigInteger? It does pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: I want to understand it.

Comment: @Ehryk I'd say the best way to understand something is to look at it's source code: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Numerics/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs

Comment: Better yet, look at the [CoreFX implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Runtime.Numerics/src/System/Numerics/BigInteger.cs). Unlike the reference source, CoreFX's license allows you to adapt the code to your own needs. `BigInteger` internally stores the value in a format *very* close to what you want. It should require only minimal changes to extract the parsing of a number to use a `byte` array rather than an `uint` array.

Comment: I'm not looking to understand all of System.Numerics, nor am I sure that's extensible to other radixes (like Octal). I'd like to know how to do it in C# without System.Numerics or regurgitating enough of System.Numerics to basically be including it.

Comment: If you do a search for converting base 10 to binary (which you should realise is very similar to what you're attempting), you'll realise that any solution needs to operate over the entire input to generate each output (or at least to prepare for the next step). So, simply, there's no way to "start at the beginning of the string, working forward".

Comment: You can't process decimal numbers in a left to right manner because 10 is not a power of two and the carried bits are only discovered after processing has begun.  The reason left to right processing works with binary, octal and hex is that there are no unused bits that rely on data to the right that has not yet been processed.  You could use buffer arrays to cache bits but this would require the buffer to be as large as the original string (in the worst case) so that's not worth it.

Comment: ...imagine someone hands you a stack of paper with a HUGE decimal number printed on it and you start reading it left to right, you simply have no idea what the first few hex bytes would be until you've processed the entire number.  This is a pretty interesting problem actually.  I'll have a think.

Comment: @Wossname: I'm fine with a buffer array the same size as the original string, I'm not really after performance here.

Comment: @Ehryk it's not about size, its about the difference between 127=0b01111111 and 128=0b10000000 - you see, the front of your array changes in binary, while the last digit changes in decimal. You simply can't construct the beginning of your binary array before you read the end of the decimal. Reading the string in reverse order might be an option, I have not evaluated that yet.

Comment: @grek40 I'm open to both options, and stated as such.

Comment: @Ehryk ok, looked into it a bit more... lets take 1 million (10^6) as an example decimal, which results in the following power-of-2 combination `2^19 + 2^18 + 2^17 + 2^16 + 2^14 + 2^9 + 2^6`. So basically, you have a single digit *somewhere* in your string and you already have to touch 4 different byte values for it. I'd take it as a hint, that the complexity per digit is linear with the digit position and thus the complexity for constructing a whole number string is in O(n^2). There might be some sophisticated linq expression for it, but its far from _directly_

Comment: Yeah, I think assembling it in reverse order would be better. Is this possible with LINQ?

Answer (score 2):

I just couldn't resist building a somewhat working solution to this question. However, as I already commented, calling the approach *directly* is a bit of an overstatement and the presented code is neigher input-validating nor efficient.

My basic approach is as follow:

1. Convert each digit to a list of zero based bit indices, associated with the index position of the digit
2. Transform the bit index list according to the digit position

   - Used approach: `value * 10 == value * (8 + 2) == (value << 3) + (value << 1)`
3. Summarize bit indices by eliminating two equal index values and adding their successor value (bitwise addition)

Theoretically it would be enough to apply bit addition once at the end, but in reality, intermediate compression is needed to avoid out of memory exceptions for large numbers

```
// example input
string input = "6524562164126412641206685";

var result = input
    // interpret the string as a list of digits with position
    .Reverse()
    // transfer from list of positioned digits to list of actual bit positions,
    // by repeatedly multiplying with 10
    // the resulting bits need to be added for the final result
    .SelectMany((x, i) =>
    {
        // digit value
        var val1 = x - '0';
        var res1 = new List<int>();
        // to bit positions, as if it was the first digit
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
        {
            if ((val1 & (1 << j)) != 0) res1.Add(j);
        }
        // to absolute bit positions, taking the digit position into account
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        {
            var res = new List<int>();
            // multiply by 10, until actual position is reached
            foreach (var item in res1)
            {
                res.Add(item + 1);
                res.Add(item + 3);
            }
            // compress bits
            res1 = res.Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(), (set, i1) =>
                {
                    // two bits in the same position add up to one bit in a higher position
                    while (set.Contains(i1))
                    {
                        set.Remove(i1);
                        i1++;
                    }
                    set.Add(i1);
                    return set;
                }).ToList();
        }
        return res1;
    }).
    // final elimination of duplicate bit indices
    Aggregate(new HashSet<int>(), (set, i) =>
    {
        while (set.Contains(i))
        {
            set.Remove(i);
            i++;
        }
        set.Add(i);
        return set;
    })
    // transfer bit positions into a byte array - lowest bit is the last bit of the first byte
    .Aggregate(new byte[(long)Math.Ceiling(input.Length / 2.0)], (res, bitpos) =>
    {
        res[bitpos / 8] |= (byte)(1 << (bitpos % 8));
        return res;
    });
```

Actually splitting the actions into separate functions would be recommended instead of this huge linq blob ;)

Comment: Since you know a ton about linq, could you take a look at how I've implemented GetOctalBytes (somewhat based off your example) and give me a few pointers? https://github.com/Ehryk/HashCompute/blob/master/SourceCode/Core/Extensions.cs

Comment: "256".ToDecimalBytes() => Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Ehryk fixed. Sorry, it was a bit late yesterday, so I didn't check all cases when I evaluated, that the byte-array length should be half the input string length.

Comment: @Ehryk Regarding your `GetOctalBytes` function: thats a tad bit offtopic, so you may want to start a question on CodeReview, if you want feedback. I can give you one pointer though: If you use the `.SelectMany((element, index) => { ... })` overload, you should be able to compute your byte-array location in one pass instead of going through the bool-array.

Comment: Question asked: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120111/converting-from-strings-to-byte-arrays-with-linq-in-c

Answer (score 0):

5 years late but maybe this might help someone else:

```
public static byte[] GetHexBytes(this string hex)
{
    return BigInteger.Parse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber).ToByteArray(true);
}

public static byte[] GetDecimalBytes(this string dec)
{
     return BigInteger.Parse(dec).ToByteArray(true);
}

// Example:
using System.Numerics;

byte[] inHex = "FFFF".GetHexBytes();      // => [ 0xFF, 0xFF ]
byte[] inDec = "65535".GetDecimalBytes(); // => [ 0xFF, 0xFF ]
```